# How to loop against directories

Tags: makefile

I am trying to build a generic task that will execute other task. What I need it to do is to loop against directories and use each dir name executing other task for it.

This is what I have:

```
# GENERIC TASKS
all-%:
    for BIN in `ls cmd`; do
        @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory BIN=$(BIN) $*
    done
```

But I get this error, could anyone explain to me how can I make it work
`` bash
➜ make all-build
for BIN in `ls cmd`; do
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [all-build] Error 2 ``

UPDATE
this is how the complete flow of my makefile looks like:

```
all-%:
    for BIN in `ls cmd`; do \
        @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory BIN=$BIN $*; \
    done
build-%:
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory BIN=$* build
build:
    docker build --no-cache --build-arg BIN=$(BIN) -t $(BIN) .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line of a make-recipe is executed in a distinct invocation of the shell.

Your recipe fails with a shell-syntax error because this line:

```
for BIN in `ls cmd`; do
```

is not a valid shell command. Nor is the third line:

```
done
```

To have all three lines executed in a single shell you must join them
into a single shell command with make's line-continuation character `\`:

```
# GENERIC TASKS
all-%:
    for BIN in `ls cmd`; do \
        @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory BIN=$$BIN $*; \
    done
```

Note also `BIN=$$BIN`, not `$(BIN)`. `BIN` is a shell variable here, not a make variable: `$$` escapes `$`-expansion by make, to preserve the shell-expansion `$BIN`.

Comment: That is correct but not sufficient.  You also need to use the _shell_ variable `$BIN` inside the loop, not the _make_ variable `$(BIN)`, which is never set to anything.  To do this you need to escape the `$`, so: `... BIN=$$BIN $*; ...`

Comment: @MadScientist Indeed, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ls` to drive the loop in Make is an [antipattern](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls) even in shell script (you want `for f in cmd/*` if I'm guessing correctly) but doubly so in a Makefile. A proper design would be to let `make` know what the dependencies are, and take it from there.

```
all-%: %: $(patsubst cmd/%,%,$(wildcard cmd/*))
        $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -$(MAKEFLAGS) BIN=$< $*
```

Comment: `Makefile:5: *** mixed implicit and static pattern rules.  Stop.`

Comment: Maybe I guessed wrong about your directory structure.  Is the `%` in `all-%` referring to a directory? Maybe try `$(patsubst cmd/%,all-%,,$(wildcard cmd/*)):` as the entire dependency line.

Comment: no the % means another makefile task in a generic task name

Comment: So what's the relationship between the task and `cmd`, which I have assumed is a directory?

Comment: yes cmd is a directory containing other directories, based on cmd I want to set BIN variable and based on `all-%` I want to run proper task

Comment: So `make all-fnord` should `make fnord` once for each `BIN` directory in `cmd`? Is the list of `all-%` targets enumerated somewhere or possible to calculate within the Makefile?

Comment: And againg what does `%` stand for? Do you have a variable which contains the values, or could one be calculated somehow?

Comment: it can not be calculated, this is for a docker image i want to set up with a makefile, in docker conf it is a value for system variable

Comment: I have extended my example makefile in question